# How to output an expression to an external file in "plain text" format without breaking lines?

Tags: export, output-formatting, streams

Given a pretty long expression, such as

```
a={-11 ψ^2 λ[1]+6 ψ λ[2],35 ψ^2 λ[2],11 ψ^2 λ[1]^2-11 ψ^2 λ[2]-6 ψ λ[1] λ[2],ψ^2 λ[1]^2-ψ^2 λ[2]-ψ λ[1] λ[2]+λ[2]^2,-λ[1]^3+2 λ[1] λ[2],-3 ψ λ[1]^3+6 ψ λ[1] λ[2]+λ[1]^2 λ[2]-λ[2]^2,-ψ λ[1]^3+λ[1]^4+2 ψ λ[1] λ[2]-3 λ[1]^2 λ[2]+λ[2]^2}
```

`a >> tmp` would output the expression of `a` to an external file `tmp`. But I don't like the format in this output. It breaks lines, and contains extra spaces between operators of "+-*/".

In fact, in *Mathematica*, selecting an expression, we could do **(right click)** > **Copy as** > **Plain Text**, and then we could paste it to any external text editor without any problem.

Is it possible to specify the output stream using this "Plain Text" format above?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
Export["test.txt", {a}]
```

works for me

`"Plaintext"` is already the default output form of `Export`. The `{  }` around `a` prevents `Export` from seeing it as a series of arguments (`a` is a list in your example) that each have to be put on its own line.

Comment: +1 ... or at least is the output form derived from the file extension ".txt" which can, alternatively, be specified directly if needed - e.g.  `Export["test.sh",{a},"Text"]`

Comment: In some cases `Export`ing as `"Text"` can corrupt the exported *Mathematica* expression. The only safe format is `"Package"` but it adds the extra line `(* Created with the Wolfram Language : www.wolfram.com *)`.

Comment: Please see my answer for some workarounds.

Answer (score 8):

### Original answer

You can stay with `Put` using the method I showed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6441361/590388) for `PutAppend`:

```
SetOptions[OpenWrite, PageWidth -> Infinity];
a >> tmp
```

This method is especially useful in the case of `PutAppend` because it allows you to maintain a running log file with results of intermediate computations with one expression per line.

---

### UPDATE: a bug introduced in version 10 (fixed in version 11.3)

There is a bug introduced in version 10: `SetOptions` no longer affects the behavior of `OpenWrite` and `OpenAppend`:

```
SetOptions[OpenWrite, PageWidth -> Infinity];
str = OpenWrite["log.txt"]; Write[str, Table[x, {50}]];
Close[str];
Import["log.txt"] // FullForm
```

> "{x, x, x, x, x, x, x, x, x, x, x, x, x, x, x, x, x, x, x, x, x, x, x,
>   x, x, \n x, x, x, x, x, x, x, x, x, x, x, x, x, x, x, x, x, x, x, x,
>   x, x, x, x, x}"

As one can see, the newline character `\n` is embedded despite the fact that `OpenWrite` is set to have the `PageWidth -> Infinity` option system-wide. A workaround is to explicitly set `PageWidth -> Infinity` for the stream:

```
str = OpenWrite["log.txt", PageWidth -> Infinity]; 
Write[str, Table[x, {50}]];
Close[str];
Import["log.txt"] // FullForm
DeleteFile["log.txt"]
```

> "{x, x, x, x, x, x, x, x, x, x, x, x, x, x, x, x, x, x, x, x, x, x, x,
>   x, x, x, x, x, x, x, x, x, x, x, x, x, x, x, x, x, x, x, x, x, x, x,
>   x, x, x, x}"

Another workaround is to `Export` as `"Text"` but **not directly**: direct exporting can corrupt the *Mathematica* expression. Instead one should explicitly convert the expression into the corresponding `InputForm` string as follows:

```
Export["test.txt", ToString[a, InputForm]]
```

An alternative is to pre-wrap the expression both by `OutputForm` and `InputForm` as follows:

```
Export["test.txt", OutputForm[InputForm[a]]]
```

Comment: This seems to no longer work for `PutAppend` in Mathematica 10.

Comment: There is a bug introduced in v.10: `SetOptions` no longer affects the behavior of `OpenWrite` and `OpenAppend`.

Answer (score 4):

Perhaps you could use Export instead of Put?

```
out = StringReplace[ToString[InputForm[a]], {" " | "\n" -> ""}]
Export["out.txt", out]
```

Answer (score 3):

Try using Export and Import.

Make sure to include `"Data"` as the second argument of `Import`.

```
SetDirectory[$TemporaryDirectory];
Export["myfile.txt", a]
in = Import["myfile.txt", "Data"]
```

[image: data]

---

If you really want to see the Greek letters spelled out you can then use

```
FullForm[in]
```

but this will also return `List[]` instead of `{}`.

Answer (score 3):

I can't get Alexey's solution to work on Mathematica 10, so I use this custom function to output simple strings in lieu of `PutAppend`:

```
myPutAppend[string_String, pathtofile_] := Module[
  {f},
  f = OpenAppend[pathtofile];
  WriteString[f, string <> "\n"];
  Close[f]
]
```

The `\n` bit is needed because `WriteString` does not automatically add it to the end of the line like the original `PutAppend`.

You can also have

```
myPut[string_String, pathtofile_] := Module[
  {f},
  f = OpenWrite[pathtofile];
  WriteString[f, string <> "\n"];
  Close[f]
]
```

for the equivalent of `Put`.

Answer (score 2):

Using undocumented [`` FrontEnd`ExportPacket ``](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/1411/280) command you can get exactly the same formatting as with `Copy As ► Plain Text` (i.e. without the line breaks and extra spaces):

```
s = First[FrontEndExecute[FrontEnd`ExportPacket[Cell[BoxData[ToBoxes[a]]], "PlainText"]]]
```

> {-11 \[Psi]^2 \[Lambda][1]+6 \[Psi] \[Lambda][2],35 \[Psi]^2 \[Lambda][2],11 \[Psi]^2 \[Lambda][1]^2-11 \[Psi]^2 \[Lambda][2]-6 \[Psi] \[Lambda][1] \[Lambda][2],\[Psi]^2 \[Lambda][1]^2-\[Psi]^2 \[Lambda][2]-\[Psi] \[Lambda][1] \[Lambda][2]+\[Lambda][2]^2,-\[Lambda][1]^3+2 \[Lambda][1] \[Lambda][2],-3 \[Psi] \[Lambda][1]^3+6 \[Psi] \[Lambda][1] \[Lambda][2]+\[Lambda][1]^2 \[Lambda][2]-\[Lambda][2]^2,-\[Psi] \[Lambda][1]^3+\[Lambda][1]^4+2 \[Psi] \[Lambda][1] \[Lambda][2]-3 \[Lambda][1]^2 \[Lambda][2]+\[Lambda][2]^2}

You can directly copy it into the clipboard with `CopyToClipboard`, and `WriteString` or `Export` as `"Text"` with safety:

```
CopyToClipboard@s

WriteString["test.txt", s, "\n"]

Export["test.txt", s]
```