# Weird behaviour with PutAppend

Tags: export, output-formatting

I'm a *Mathematica* newbie and I'm trying to append some data to a file but I am experiencing some weird behaviour when using `PutAppend`.

Here is what I am doing:

```
AbsVal[T_, numofterms_, a_] := Abs[B2[T, numofterms, a]/numint[T, a]][[1]]

For[n = 1, n < 500, n += 5, PutAppend[Flatten[{n, AbsVal[t, n, a]}], "myfile.txt"]]
```

I'll now give you example of the outputs. For

```
AbsVal[t, n, a]
```

I get an output with the following format:

```
3.090061579944379*10^-416
```

But in my file I see

```
{1, 
 6.634398712795078837941035470191903174478256263992767`15.954589770191005*^-4\
30}
{6, 3.0900615799443788409187442259678172695491469841`15.954589770191005*^-416}
{11, 2.1455743830188223575511135886399984856855`15.954589770191005*^-403}
{16, 
 2.2729950468097654970709463565988731409032630716722417`15.954589770191005*^-\
391}
{21, 6.0066411663977041046546546698428746195726683`15.954589770191005*^-380}
{26, 5.31062408165803191323563134185348816`15.954589770191005*^-369}
{31, 
 1.9022430662165668797880573883969431578102581385`15.954589770191005*^-358}
{36, 3.1567662580039551788994831970476421271`15.954589770191005*^-348}
{41, 
 2.67979361914634680070557971109230909959314472123`15.954589770191005*^-338}
{46, 1.25574842187340348082241748599920258043`15.954589770191005*^-328}
{51, 3.450109407850428362698276923292493910486398948`15.954589770191005*^-319}
{56, 5.8363462554023196163570433861000185804`15.954589770191005*^-310}
{61, 6.330104189030497*^-301}
{66, 4.55439511956804*^-292}
{71, 2.237735694265989*^-283}
{76, 7.698747588846684*^-275}
{81, 1.895566134531356*^-266}
(...)
```

which I think is very weird because:

- In the first line, there is a linebreak between `1,` and `6.6343987(blah blah blah)`
- Sometimes I have that weird `` `15.954589770191005 `` term with that weird apostrophe (which I have no idea what it means)
- Also sometime I get a backslash `\` when the line gets too long

As you have noticed, this is all very weird to me!!

What I'm aiming for is for a consistent output like the one we see in the last five lines. What I was **REALLY** aiming for is to have a csv format as output (without the curly brackets)

What am I doing wrong? or what do I need to configure to fix this?

Thank you very much!

Comment: The part after the backtick is the number of digits of precision in the preceding number.

Comment: I'm not quite sure what your `Flatten[]` is doing--it doesn't look to me like it's needed there.

Comment: @sblom, I have accidentally deleted your answer when trying to vote up!! Sorry!! I don't think I can undo this??

Comment: @T.P.Vasconcelos No worry, you cannot directly delete the comment or answer of others by clicking on them :) It may have been removed by sblom when you were voting up.

Comment: @xavier not even on my own questions? how did his comment disappear?

Comment: @T.P.Vasconcelos No, not even on your own question. See edited comment above for the second question.

Comment: Use `Export`.  `Put` will write Mathematica expressions, and you don't want Mathematica syntax in your output.  The usual way to export data is to first generate all of it, then `Export` a whole list in one go.  Always do this unless you know why you need to append step by step. If you're new to Mathematica forget about `For` completely, as it will be counterproductive to your learning.  For procedural loops use `Do` instead, or `While` when needed.  But try to avoid procedural loops.  The right way to deal with your example is to generate data with `Table`, then `Export`.

Comment: The link above is about appending in CSV format, for the rare cases when that is necessary.  But do consider something like this first: `result = Table[{n, AbsVal[t, n, a]}, {n, 1, 50, 5}];
Export["output.csv", result]`.

Comment: Related: ["How to output an expression to an external file in “plain text” format without breaking lines?"](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/9977/280)

Comment: @T.P.Vasconcelos Yeah--I deleted it; you didn't. :) My solution wasn't working quite right, and rather than spread slightly broken info that I didn't have time to fix up, I figured I'd let others take a shot at answering. Looks like you found a good fix!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Found the answer to my question!!

```
For[n = 1, n < 50, n += 5, {n, FortranForm[AbsVal[t, n, a]]} >>> "myfile.txt"]
```

which appends the following output to myfile.txt

```
{1, 6.634398712795079e-430}
{6, 3.090061579944379e-416}
{11, 2.145574383018822e-403}
{16, 2.272995046809765e-391}
{21, 6.006641166397704e-380}
{26, 5.310624081658032e-369}
{31, 1.902243066216567e-358}
{36, 3.156766258003955e-348}
{41, 2.679793619146347e-338}
{46, 1.255748421873403e-328}
```

I'm happy with this for now!